# How to resolve the build error for deployement with CAS

Tags: java

I am deploying CAS for the first time. It's for my soutenance (licence in security). I have success to build and run the cas-overlay-template and authenticate with casuser; my problem is with cas-management-overlay, I have success to build the war but running send error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :run FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jMarkerFactory)'
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider.initialize(SLF4JServiceProvider.java:54)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:421)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:407)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:356)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:382)
        at org.apereo.cas.util.ResourceUtils.<clinit>(ResourceUtils.java:40)
        at org.apereo.cas.mgmt.CasManagementBanner.loadGitProperties(CasManagementBanner.java:52)
        at org.apereo.cas.mgmt.CasManagementBanner.<clinit>(CasManagementBanner.java:45)
        at org.apereo.cas.mgmt.CasManagementEmbeddedContainerUtils.getCasManagementBannerInstance(CasManagementEmbeddedContainerUtils.java:41)
        at org.apereo.cas.mgmt.web.CasManagementWebApplication.main(CasManagementWebApplication.java:70)
        ... 8 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/dgtcp/cas-management-overlay/build.gradle' line: 86

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 25s
5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

My build.gradle file :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.*
import org.gradle.internal.logging.text.*
import org.apereo.cas.metadata.*
import java.nio.file.*
import static org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput.Style

buildscript {
    repositories {
        if (project.privateRepoUrl) {
          maven {
            url project.privateRepoUrl
            credentials {
              username = project.privateRepoUsername
              password = System.env.PRIVATE_REPO_TOKEN
            }
          }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
#        maven {
#            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
#            mavenContent { snapshotsOnly() }
#        }
#        maven {
#            url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone"
#            mavenContent { releasesOnly() }
#        }
#    }
#    dependencies {
#        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${project.springBootVersion}"

#  /**
#    * Do NOT modify the lines below or else you will risk breaking dependency management.
#    */
#    implementation enforcedPlatform("org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-bom:${project.'cas.version'}")
#    implementation platform(org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)

#    /**
#     * CAS dependencies and modules may be listed here.
#     *
#     * There is no need to specify the version number for each dependency
#     * since versions are all resolved and controlled by the dependency management
#     * plugin via the CAS bom.
#     **/

#    implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-core-api-configuration-model"
#    implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-webapp-init"

#    if (project.hasProperty("casModules")) {
#        def dependencies = project.getProperty("casModules").split(",")
#        dependencies.each {
#           def projectsToAdd = rootProject.subprojects.findAll {project ->
#               project.name == "cas-server-core-${it}" || project.name == "cas-server-support-${it}"
#            }
#            projectsToAdd.each {implementation it}
#        }
#    }


#    developmentOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:${project.springBootVersion}"
#}
```